# Merge and add duplicate integers from a multidimensional array

Tags: python

I have a multidimensional list where the first item is a date and the second is a date time object needing to be added together. For example (leave the second as a integer for simplicity):

```
[[01/01/2019, 10], [01/01/2019, 3], [02/01/2019, 4], [03/01/2019, 2]]
```

The resulting array should be:

```
[[01/01/2019, 13], [02/01/2019, 4], [03/01/2019, 2]]
```

Does someone have a short way of doing this?

The background to this is vehicle tracking, I have a list of trips performed by vehicle and I want to have a summary by day with a count of total time driven per day.

Comment: use a dictionary for that, if you have problems with it, post what you have tried and I am sure someone will help you fix it

Comment: why 01/01/2019 + 01/01/2019 = 01/01/2019? what shall be the result of e.g. 01/01/2019 + 05/01/2019? Furthermore, why do not you add the first element of the 3rd element to the other first elements of first and second elements?

Comment: Yes, use a dictionary, treat it as a string and use it as key, also youy should post what youy tried, we will not write code for you

Comment: I have a large list of arrays which are vehicle trips, multiple trips occur during a day. As you can see the first item is a date and the second represents the duration of that trip. The objective is to have a list of the date and total duration for trips that day.

Comment: Thanks Derte and E.Serra, will give it a go :) who voted the question down, how can I improve my question?

Comment: have a look at map, reduce, filter, dict comprehension, Counter etc.

Comment: You can add some code, please..

Comment: check my answer below please

Comment: could you accept one of the answers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your data 01/01/2019 to '01/01/2019'.

@naivepredictor suggested good sample, anyway, if you don't want to import pandas, use this.

```
my_list = [['01/01/2019', 10], ['01/01/2019', 3], ['02/01/2019', 4], ['03/01/2019', 2]]
result_d = {}

for i in my_list:
    result_d[i[0]] = result_d.get(i[0], 0) + i[1]  

print(result_d) #{'01/01/2019': 13, '02/01/2019': 4, '03/01/2019': 2}
print([list(d) for d in result_d.items()]) #[['01/01/2019', 13], ['02/01/2019', 4], ['03/01/2019', 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks Dahyun, this is great, don't need any extra libraries, however I do need to change the date to a string, which is no problem as its being passed from Django to JQuery which will convert from UTC anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe out of the given imput
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['01/01/2019', 10], ['01/01/2019', 3], ['02/01/2019', 4]], columns=['date', 'trip_len'])

# groupby date and sum values for each day
df = df.groupby('date').sum().reset_index()

# output result as list of lists
result = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer mate, this is great, however I need to use the pandas library.  Do you know anything about the efficiency of the operation?

Comment: I leave it to you to have a play with timeit module and compare various results from pandas vs dict vs numpy operations :) Pandas is fast and I would recommend really to look at numpy and various dict operations yourself. You can try https://github.com/modin-project/modin also

Comment: for sure the pandas solution is slower than the one presented by Dahyun Yu. For 100 times execution in a loop the results are: Dahyun Yu: ~0.0, naivepredictor: 0.28600025177001953